# UWP FolderPicker Select Folder button disabled by default?

Tags: user-interface, uwp, dialog, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I have a simple code for `FolderPicker`:

```
        var diagFolder = new FolderPicker();
        diagFolder.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        var outputFolder = await diagFolder.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        if (outputFolder == null) { return; }
```

It works well on first launch. However, upon second call, the `Select Folder` button is disabled and user cannot choose the same folder although it is perfectly valid. I have to go back a level and re-enter the folder if I want to pick that same folder.

[image]

Anyone is having this problem and know a fix for it?

EDIT: as of my guess, it is not actually UWP code problem, but Windows problem, so I posted a feedback here: https://aka.ms/AA1hloz . I think voting there should help.

Comment: Hi, did you establish any solution to that problem? I can't seem to open the link you provided.

Comment: @GeorgiG The link is opened by Feedback Hub app on Windows 10. There seem to be no web version so that's the only link I can share. And it's a Windows 10 problem, so no, we can't do anything about it. Someone commented on the issue that 1803 still has the problem, no idea if it's fixed now.

Comment: Any update on this? It still behaves this way, why can't the initial folder be used directly?